# Array elements are not being displayed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, filter, web

I'm currently trying to create a filter system for a festival website. I have gotten the price filter working however now I'm trying to filter the genre.

I'm using an array called `filterfestivals` for the genre filter, this array only contains elements that have been pushed from the price filter. Whenever I try to alert this array after the genre filter, the alert is always blank? Thanks for any replies.

Code:

```js
// Festival[x][0]   city[x][1]           cost[x][2]    date[x][3]                genre[x][4]
var festivals = [
  ["Reading",       "Richfield Avenue",  205,          "24th - 26th August",     "Rock"],
  ["Park Life",     "Manchester",        140,          "8th - 9th June",         "Pop"],
  ["Glastonbury",   "Somerset",          250,          "23rd - 25th June",       "Alternative"],
  ["Lovebox",       "London",            120,          "8th - 9th June",         "Pop"],
  ["Bluedot",       "Macclesfield",      175,          "19th - 22nd July",       "Alternative"],
  ["Bestival",      "Dorset",            192,          "2nd - 5th August",       "Dance"],
  ["V festival",    "Staffordshire",     140,          "18th - 19th August",     "Pop"],
  ["Latitude",      "Suffolk",           197,          "12th - 15th July",       "Dance"],
  ["Download",      "Derby",             200,          "14th - 16th June",       "Rock"],
];
var filterfestivals = [[]];    

function filter(){
  var maxuserprice = document.getElementById("maxprice").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < festivals.length; i++)
    if (maxuserprice > festivals[i][2]){
      filterfestivals.push(festivals[i])
      //i = i + 1
    }

  var usergenre = document.getElementById("festivalgenre").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < filterfestivals.length; i++)
    if (usergenre != filterfestivals[i][4]){
      filterfestivals.splice(filterfestivals[i])
    }
  alert(filterfestivals)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p1> Please enter your maximum spending price </p1>
  <input id="maxprice" />
  <button onclick="filter()"> Filter </button>
  <br />
  <p1> Select a genre </p1>
  <select id="festivalgenre">
    <option value="Rock"> Rock </option>
    <option value="Pop"> Pop </option>
    <option value="Alternative"> Alternative </option>
    <option value="Dance"> Dance </option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Array.prototype.filter()` to filter your records

```js
var festivals = [
                ["Reading",       "Richfield Avenue",  205,          "24th - 26th August",     "Rock"],
                ["Park Life",     "Manchester",        140,          "8th - 9th June",         "Pop"],
                ["Glastonbury",   "Somerset",          250,          "23rd - 25th June",       "Alternative"],
                ["Lovebox",       "London",            120,          "8th - 9th June",         "Pop"],
                ["Bluedot",       "Macclesfield",      175,          "19th - 22nd July",       "Alternative"],
                ["Bestival",      "Dorset",            192,          "2nd - 5th August",       "Dance"],
                ["V festival",    "Staffordshire",     140,          "18th - 19th August",     "Pop"],
                ["Latitude",      "Suffolk",           197,         "12th - 15th July",       "Dance"],
                ["Download",      "Derby",             200,           "14th - 16th June",       "Rock"],
                ];


function filter(){
  var maxuserprice = document.getElementById("maxprice").value;
  var usergenre = document.getElementById("festivalgenre").value;
  var filterfestivals = festivals.filter(item => maxuserprice > item[2]);
  filterfestivals = filterfestivals.filter(item => item[4] === usergenre);
  alert(filterfestivals)
}
```

```html
<p1> Please enter your maximum spending price </p1>
<input id = "maxprice"> </input>
<button onclick = "filter()"> Filter </button>
<br />
<p1> Select a genre </p1>
<select id = "festivalgenre">
        <option value = "Rock"> Rock </option>
        <option value = "Pop"> Pop </option>
        <option value = "Alternative"> Alternative </option>
        <option value = "Dance"> Dance </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can see this works but what exactly does Array.prototype.filter() do?

Comment: It filters array items and returns a new array. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

You are using splice incorrectly.

Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
```

> start
>
> Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). [...]
>
> deleteCount
>
> If deleteCount is omitted, or if its value is larger than array.length - start (that is, if it is greater than the number of elements left in the array, starting at start), then all of the elements from start through the end of the array will be deleted.

Or you can simply use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as stated by @Zohaib Ijaz